# toString method on array of objects called from recursion method

Tags: java, arrays, object, recursion, tostring

```
class Anadromi001
    {
        public void Anadromi01 (Foititis[] F, short ap01, short i)
            {
                if (ap01 == 4) System.exit(0);
                Anadromi002 obj02 = new Anadromi002();
                String onoma, epitheto;
                short MesOr;
                int AritMit, EtosEis;
                short ap02;
                boolean flag00, flag02, flag03;
                int k, f, l = 0;          
                k = F.length-1
[...]
case 3:
                        f = obj02.Anadromi02(F, l);
                        if (f == -1) System.out.println("O pinakas einai adeios.");
                        else 
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j <= f; j++)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(F[j].toString());
                                    }
                            }
                        //System.out.println(f);
                        break;
                    }
    }
```

This is the part of my code, what i want to do is if I call a second recursion (the current code is a recursion itself) and then use the value from the second recursion to print my toString method (placed in the object class). Pay no attention to `case 3` it is just a "code" for the user to choose what to do in the program.

```
class Foititis 
    {
        String onoma, epitheto;
        short MesOr;
        int AritMit, EtosEis;
        public Foititis (String on, String ep, int AM, int EE,  short MO)
            {
                onoma = on;
                epitheto = ep;
                AritMit = AM;
                EtosEis = EE;
                MesOr = MO;
            }

        public String toString()
            {
                String emf;
                emf = "--------------------" + "\n";
                emf = "Onoma: " + onoma + "\n";
                emf = "Epwnymo: " + epitheto + "\n";
                emf = "Arithmos Mitrwoy: " + AritMit + "\n";
                emf = "Etos Eisagwnis: " + EtosEis + "\n";
                emf = "Mesos Oros Mathimatwn: " + MesOr + "\n";
                emf = "--------------------";
                return emf;
            }
    }
```

All I get as output, when I execute the program, is: `--------------------`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
emf = emf + "Prevous line" + "\n";
```

on every new line.
 Your only last line is printing.

Correct format would be:

```
              emf = "--------------------" + "\n"+
              "Onoma: " + onoma + "\n"+
              "Epwnymo: " + epitheto + "\n"+
              "Arithmos Mitrwoy: " + AritMit + "\n"+
              "Etos Eisagwnis: " + EtosEis + "\n"+
              "Mesos Oros Mathimatwn: " + MesOr + "\n"+
               "--------------------";
```

OR

```
        emf = "--------------------" + "\n";
        emf = emf +  "Onoma: " + onoma + "\n";
        emf = emf + "Epwnymo: " + epitheto + "\n";
        emf = emf + "Arithmos Mitrwoy: " + AritMit + "\n";
        emf = emf + "Etos Eisagwnis: " + EtosEis + "\n";
        emf = emf + "Mesos Oros Mathimatwn: " + MesOr + "\n";
        emf = emf + "--------------------";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+=` instead of `=` to concatenate strings, or you will see what is asssigned lastly.

```
public String toString()
    {
        String emf;
        emf = "--------------------" + "\n";
        emf += "Onoma: " + onoma + "\n";
        emf += "Epwnymo: " + epitheto + "\n";
        emf += "Arithmos Mitrwoy: " + AritMit + "\n";
        emf += "Etos Eisagwnis: " + EtosEis + "\n";
        emf += "Mesos Oros Mathimatwn: " + MesOr + "\n";
        emf += "--------------------";
        return emf;
    }
```

Or simply

```
public String toString()
    {
        return "--------------------" + "\n" +
               "Onoma: " + onoma + "\n" +
               "Epwnymo: " + epitheto + "\n" +
               "Arithmos Mitrwoy: " + AritMit + "\n" +
               "Etos Eisagwnis: " + EtosEis + "\n" +
               "Mesos Oros Mathimatwn: " + MesOr + "\n" +
               "--------------------";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are actually assigning new value in every line instead of appending. so it is only showing the last line. From second assignment, you can use

```
emf += <your string>
```

or you can use a stringbuilder and append the lines.. and finally the toString